# Python (comma separated values)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary as:

```
dict_1 = {'A' : {'C10' : 5},
    'A,B' : {'C11' : 5, 'C12' : 4},
    'A,B,C' : {'C10' : 3, 'C12' : 5},
    'C,D' : {'C11' : 4}
}
```

And want an output as:

```
result = {'A' : [{'C10' : 5}, {'C11' : 5, 'C12' : 4}, {'C10' : 3, 'C12' : 5}],
          'B' : [{'C11' : 5, 'C12' : 4}, {'C10' : 3, 'C12' : 5}],
          'C' : [{'C10' : 3, 'C12' : 5}, {'C11' : 4}],
          'D' : [{'C11' : 4}]
}
```

Comment: I tried by many ways. But none of it is working.

I split dict_1 into 2 dictionaries. 1 with a comma seperated value and another with the rest. I tried to match it and update it. But not working.

Comment: @deceze, why did you close this? I was just typing an answer and you shut me down in mid-stream.

Comment: @Tom Because it's an objectively bad question. It's not even a question, it's a task description.

Comment: @deceze Okay, you have a point. But there are lots of questions like that.

Comment: @Tom Unfortunately yes.

Comment: @deceze Well it is pretty annoying to spend half an hour developing a solution and typing it up in enough detail to be clear to a Python newbie, and then be blocked from entering it at the last minute.

Comment: @Tom Yes, totally understandable, and sorry for wasting your time. But we do have standards we're trying to adhere to here.

Comment: @deceze, I think once you may be a newbie.. And stack overflow has standards, i agree but it makes real coders. And frankly speaking you have no right to do so. If anyone is not getting anything, they will first search on Stack Overflow. So, whatever you have done is completely wrong.

Comment: @Tom, thank you so much.. I admire people like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in dict_1.items():
    for x in k.split(','):
        res[x].append(v)

result = dict(res)
print(result)
```

Gives you:

```
{'A': [{'C10': 5}, {'C11': 5, 'C12': 4}, {'C10': 3, 'C12': 5}],
 'B': [{'C11': 5, 'C12': 4}, {'C10': 3, 'C12': 5}],
 'C': [{'C10': 3, 'C12': 5}, {'C11': 4}],
 'D': [{'C11': 4}]}
```

Comment: How is it that you were able to put in an answer, whereas I was blocked when deceze closed it?

Comment: @TomZych I was just lucky: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible